# Azure Application Insights Alerting, Custom Events and Docker

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I created an Application Insights resource, added the Docker monitoring tile and started up a App Insights Docker container on my Docker host with my Instrumentation Key and have metrics and events flowing (as per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-docker/).

I can create alerts for metrics from the Azure Portal and was surprised to see I cannot create alerts for events (at least from the Portal itself). For example, the custom Docker event **docker-container-die**. My motivation would be to monitor and be alerted when a docker container dies unexpectedly. Am I missing something?

Based on [Application Insights Alert not firing for custom Metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232054/application-insights-alert-not-firing-for-custom-metric), is this use case just not something that App Insights is designed to solve?

Or is it more accurate to say I'd want to turn on Continuous Export and use a web job or something similar to monitor Storage for that event and then do whatever I want from there?

I don't want to twist a tool past its intended purpose, but is tempting since the data is right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently don't support alerts on top of custom events. This is in our backlog and will be enabled in the future

Comment: Is this user voice item the best place to register my interest in this feature? https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/8016897-application-insights-alert-rule-custom-events